# Java- When class A call the classB, in class B how can I use the method and attribute of classA?

Tags: java

I met one problem, I have two class `class A` and `class B` they look like:

```
class A{
 private String s;
 public a1(){
  // do something with s
  B b = new B();
  b.b1();
  // do others things
 }
 public a2(){
 // this needs s which has been initialised in method a1
 } 
}

class B{
 public b1(){
 // do something

 // here, how can I call method a2 and use String s in a2?
 A a = new A(); 
 a.a2();
 // ...
 }
}
```

How can I keep the value of `String s` when we call the method a2?
And I don't like use `b.b1(s)` in a2 and `a.a2(s)` in b1.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Huh?  If "s" is a data member of class A, then why do you think a2() does not have access to s??  Your class definitions are very strange - looks like a circular dependency.  A uses B and B uses A.  Maybe you need to re-think what it is that you are trying to accomplish. And give classes meaningful names.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you, I thought in class B we make new instance (`A a = new A();  a.a2();`), so I think in this new instance, it can't have a access to s. Do I make a mistake?

Comment: @ShireResident thanks, I got your point, the problem is how can I use the same `s` in class B when it call the method a2?

Comment: Look at Andy's response - that is a good way. Although it is difficult to suggest a clear response unless we what those methods are supposed to do and where else they are used and how. Couldn't you call a2() from within a1() after the call to b.b1()? If the code after the call to a.a2() depends on the execution of a.a2() then you couldn't. But then I would really think hard of changing my code.

Comment: @ShireResident, sorry, I can't call a2() from within a1() after call to b.b1(), because a2() which uses some data from b1(). Anyway, thank your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject the calling instance of `A` into `b1`:

```
public b1(A a) {
  ...
}
```

to avoid needing to create a new `A` in that method. Then, in `a1`, you can call it like:

```
b.b1(this);
```

This is known as [*dependency injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): the working of `b1` depends upon an instance of `A`, so you inject that dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but in your second way, we need create a new instance `A` in method b1 in order to call `a2()`, don't we?

Comment: Sure. Like I say "*if* all you actually need is the value of `s`". It is simply pointing out that you don't always have to inject the instance containing the data you want, you can simply inject the data.